Why is the daily box not being added to the inventory?
I am trying to fix the issue where the daily box is not being added to the user's inventory when the user claims their daily every 3 days consecutively.
here is the portion of the code where I try to add the daily box to the user's inventory if it's their 3rd day claiming the reward.
daily.js (line 136 to 151)
// Check if the user is eligible for a Daily Box
let dailyBoxReward = false;
let nextItemRewardDays = 3 - (streak % 3);
if (streak % 3 === 0) {
   if (!data.inventory) {
      data.inventory = {};
   }

   if (!data.inventory["Daily Box"]) {
      data.inventory["Daily Box"] = 0;
   }

   data.inventory["Daily Box"] += 1;
   dailyBoxReward = true;
   nextItemRewardDays = 3; // Reset the counter after receiving the reward
}

await data.save();

When I was testing the command, I would edit the db to have a daily streak of 3, so here is a before and after of me updating the streak in mongodb.
before:

after:

I also took a screenshot of the inventory before the execution of the daily command with a streak of 3, and it attempting to add the daily box to the inventory and after.

and just in case its asked for, here is the relivant part of the inventory and daily streak in usereconomicprofiles.js file with the schema setup.
dailyStreak: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  },
  lastMissedDaily: {
    type: Number,
  },
  inventory: {
    type: Map,
    of: Number,
    default: { "Apple": 1 } // Default item for new users
  },

I have tried to change the way it adds the daily box to the users inventory in this part
// Check if the user is eligible for a Daily Box
let dailyBoxReward = false;
let nextItemRewardDays = 3 - (streak % 3);
if (streak % 3 === 0) {
   if (!data.inventory) {
      data.inventory = {};
   }

   if (!data.inventory["Daily Box"]) {
      data.inventory["Daily Box"] = 0;
   }

   data.inventory["Daily Box"] += 1;
   dailyBoxReward = true;
   nextItemRewardDays = 3; // Reset the counter after receiving the reward
}

await data.save();

it still resulted in absolutely nothing changing in the inventory command as included in the image above, and the mongodb query.
if full code is needed to help, I will provide the 3 files below in their entirety.

daily.js
inventory.js
economicuserprofiles.js


Wrt "When I was testing the command, I would edit the db to have a daily streak of 3, so here is a before and after of me updating the streak in mongodb." - It's unclear from your whole question if you're saying that the DB query works correctly or does NOT. If it's correct in the DB then the issue is related your js application code or usage of discord.js. Read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
